# Fluent NHibernate has many with Reference Composite Key

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate

I surge on this problem a long time. So the problem is that Fluent generates an error while creating the DB shema: Foreign key (FK6FF7FBACF647ABE5:CheckListToAttributeLinkItem [ProductUID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (ProductAttributeLink [ProductUID, AttributeEntityUID]). 
Here is my entities. I'm showing there as they are (without Equals(object obj) and GetHashCode() methods for short)
First: this entity connects Product with its Parameter (Attribute). So it's a many-to-many "middle" table.:

```
public class ProductAttributeLink
{
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual AttributeEntity AttributeEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Second: this entity is the inheritor

```
public class CheckListProductAttributeLinkValue : ProductAttributeLink
{
    protected IList<CheckListToAttributeLinkItem> _values = new List<CheckListToAttributeLinkItem>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<CheckListToAttributeLinkItem> Values
    {
        get { return _values; }
    }
}
```

Third: this entity is the Attribute item

```
public class AttributeEntityValueListItem
{
    public virtual Guid UID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Item { get; set; }
    public virtual AttributeEntity AttributeEntity { get; set; }
}
```

I need many-to-many with this and previous entities (CheckListProductAttributeLinkValue and AttributeEntityValueListItem). So I created "middle" entity

```
public class CheckListToAttributeLinkItem
{
    public virtual CheckListProductAttributeLinkValue CheckListProductAttributeLinkValue { get; set; }
    public virtual AttributeEntityValueListItem AttributeEntityValueListItem { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class ProductAttributeLinkMap : ClassMap<ProductAttributeLink>
{
    public ProductAttributeLinkMap()
    { 
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Product, "ProductUID")
            .KeyReference(x => x.AttributeEntity, "AttributeEntityUID");

        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("ClassType").Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class CheckListProductAttributeLinkValueMap :   SubclassMap<CheckListProductAttributeLinkValue>
{
    public CheckListProductAttributeLinkValueMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue(@"CheckLiskValue");
        HasMany(x => x.Values)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .KeyColumns.Add("ProductUID")
            .KeyColumns.Add("AttributeEntityUID")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class CheckListToAttributeLinkItemMap : ClassMap<CheckListToAttributeLinkItem>
{
    public CheckListToAttributeLinkItemMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.CheckLinkProductAttributeLinkValue, "ProductUID", "AttributeEntityUID")
            .KeyReference(x => x.AttributeEntityValueListItem, "AttributeEntityValueListItemUID");
    }
}
public class AttributeEntityValueListItemMap : ClassMap<AttributeEntityValueListItem>
{
    public AttributeEntityValueListItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Item);
        References(x => x.AttributeEntity);
    }
}
```

Comment: which Version of FNH are you using? There was a bug with Subclass and multiple columns. see: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/issues/194

Comment: Thanks. I'm feeling this is the same bug. I solved this problem another way, not as nice as it should have been, but it works. Waiting for new version with bug fixed...